# C - Adjusting my program to read a file line-by-line without setting a maximum length on each line with fscanf

Tags: c, memory-management, file-io, scanf, fgets

I'm learning C and how to read/write based on file contents, but I'm having some difficulty.

Currently in this test program, I'm attempting to read from the file test.txt line-by-line **without** specifying the max length of the line, so basically I can't use fgets.

Instead, I try to use fscanf. But 1) I still have to specify an overbound for the length of the char array and 2) The program doesn't even work -- all it reads is the very first letter of the first line.

What am I doing wrong and how can I change the program so I don't have a max bound on length of each line (in this example its 1000)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit() function
int main() {
    char c[1000];
    FILE *test;
    if ((test = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! Couldn't find file");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(test, "%[^\n]", c);
    printf("Data from the file:\n%s", c);
    fclose(test);

    return 0;
}
```

for reference here's my current test.txt:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx yz
```

Comment: Post the first few lines of the file's contents.  `fscanf(test, "%[^\n]", c);` only reads up to the end of the first line.  If the line is too long -  bad things happen.

Comment: This is not the first time I see this construct in `C`: `fscanf(test, "%[^\n]", c);`. And I have real questions about it. Is it standard? What does it mean? Could we give regular expression to `scanf`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica done! the line is only four letters :(

Comment: Try `fscanf(test, "%[^\n]", c); printf("Data from the file:\n%s", c);` --> `if (fscanf(test, "%999[^\n]", c) == 1) printf("Data from the file:<%s>\n", c);`.  Notice the re-ordered output format.

Comment: You only attempt one read operation — and you don't ensure that doesn't overflow your buffer.  You also don't check whether it worked.  If it was in a loop, the second call would fail because the newline would be left in the input stream, and that doesn't match the format string.  You'll be best off using [`fgets()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or perhaps POSIX [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).  Failing that, you can use `fscanf(test, "%999[^\n]%*c", c)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i didnt get any output when i tried that

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sadly im hoping to transition to not having a buffer or max length of line variable :(

Comment: "hoping to transition to not having a buffer or max length of line variable" --> where you you like such a function to put the data? Auto allocate memory for you?  Drop characters past 999?

Comment: Hmmm, I suspect the contents of the file are not what you think they are.  It could be as simple as the first character in the file is a `\n` and not `"abcd\n"`.  Review file contents.  Another problem may be the file is [UTF16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) or has a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).. What is the length of the file?

Comment: Hmm, on 2nd though I think the file _is_ UTF16-LE as that would read `'a'`, `'\0'`, `'b'`, `'\0'` ....  Printing that out as a C string would only report `"a"`.  Please report file length.

Comment: POSIX `getline()` imposes no limit on how long the line is (up to the size representable by `ssize_t`, anyway — that's pretty big on your typical 64-bit machine).  Using `getline()` means you won't have to worry about leftover newlines.   If you're using a suitably modern box (not macOS, sadly), you can use the `%ms` conversion specification to have [`fscanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) allocate the necessary space for you.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica by file length do you mean the number of lines? also how do i check if its utf16-le?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh i see, my bad for not noticing that before. would you mind providing an explanation of what ssize_t and size_t are? I'm trying to follow the examples given on that page. also, not sure if this is related to the utf chux mentioned but when i run the first example with my test.txt file it only finds 3 lines (abcd, efgh, ijkl) and thinks the lengths of them are 6,6,4 respectively. ill try to figure out why because honestly all this is very new to me, but id appreciate your take on it too

Comment: also, id love an explanation on what the arguments in ```read = getline(&line, &len, fp)``` mean <3

Comment: The `getline()` function returns a value of type `ssize_t`, which is the signed equivalent of `size_t`.  In turn, `size_t` is the (unsigned) type used to represent the sizes of objects; it is the type returned by the `sizeof` operator.  The `getline()` function returns `-1` (not `EOF`, but the values are usually the same) when it encounters EOF, so its return type must be a signed type.  In theory, you could have a file with no newlines and gargantuan size, and `getline()` could run out of memory — there is no limit on the amount of memory it allocates — but it is unlikely on most machines.

Comment: The normal idiom for using `getline()` is: `char *line = 0; size_t len = 0; ssize_t nbytes; while ((nbytes = getline(&line, &len, fp)) > 0) {` …process line with nbytes of data, including a newline unless the file ends without one… `} free(line);`.  Note that memory is often allocated by `getline()` even if it processes an empty file.  If you want to keep the data, it's usually best to copy the line (e.g. `strdup(line)`) because `getline()` typically allocates 256 bytes or some similar number even if the input is only 5 bytes plus a null. That can lead to a lot of wasted space. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Alternatively, you can save the newly allocated `line` value somewhere and then reset `line = 0; len = 0;` before the next call to `getline()` so that more memory is allocated on each call.  Beware leaks.

Comment: Mannt, by "file length" I mean the length of the entire file in bytes.  Possible visible by looking at the properties of the file on your operating system.